# how do I make the jump from understanding C++ as a language to understanding all the acronyms that go with job postings

Tags: c++

This is a difficult question to phrase, but hopefully I can make it more transparent. Basically, I've taught myself (after a couple of grounding classes in college) how to write and compile C++ code. I have written a small handful of actual programs in Visual Studio and learned to compile them as standalone EXEs. I feel competent that if someone came up to me and said "I want you to have a program that does X, Y, and Z within the confines of the standard library," I would be able to figure it out and present something.

However, there appears to be a chasm between this and what I see when I check out Freelancer.com, Craigslist, and other sites for jobs, internships, and gigs. There are acronyms and references to I'm-not-sure-what (example post here: https://www.freelancer.com/projects/Data-Processing-CPlusPlus-Programming/Build-hash-table-using-chaining.html)

Basically, it's fine if everyone agrees there's a chasm here. I just want to know where to look to find the bridge :) Any reading materials / specific online class / etc. that I could look into? Any assistance would be stupendous.

Thanks!

Comment: that's not a typical SO question. perhaps you can be more specific about things you don't understand and people will love to explain it to you. as for the general "what should I do" question, you will only get general "you need to collect some experience" answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: The ad you've linked to is to hire someone to do their homework... If you expect to be able to do their homework without having taken the courses they've taken (where this terminology would be introduced to you), you've got a rather large challenge before you!

Comment: The link you provided sounds like a homework assignment. Specifically for a data structures course. There are many online courses in data structures.

Comment: What acronyms are you talking about in that link? It's pretty much only talking about hash tables and related terms which got nothing to do with C++ but rather with data structures and certainly should come up in a data structures course.

Comment: Usually, the acronym that most employers get wrong is "C/C++".  Other common acronyms: CLR, CLI, OS, RTOS, IDE, VS, MS, ADC, DAC, UART, USB, and GUI.

Comment: If you're not a properly trained programmer you should just do it as a hobby and get a job doing something else. Would you hire a "self-taught" electrician?

Comment: @ooga whats the difference between "self-taught" and "properly trained" if/when both have the same knowledge and experience? Even someone with all the degrees and diplomas won't do anything without practice, and one can't practice when not doing anything usefull.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I wouldn't hire a self-taught electrician. Apparently you would. That's the difference between us.

Comment: @ooga I'm not asking about the difference between us. Also there's a slight difference between an electrician and a programer (well unless the later is working on Skynet, then they both can do the same harm...).

Comment: @PawełStawarz - whats the difference? 4 years+ of computer science curriculum on topics that a self-taught programmer may never know exists. Comp Sci students have to take rigorous courses like OS Theory, Compiler Construction, Algorithm Analysis, Discrete Logic, etc. and at least come prepared. I've hired and fired a few self taught programmers who were Civil or Electrical Engineers that picked up VB.Net, PHP or Java. Almost all were at a disadvantage but they did not realize it. The really smart ones, however, learn, no matter what, school or no school. And you want them working for you.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple, experience. You don't have a lot yet, and its a lifelong process.

There is no secret, or shortcut, besides reading and participation and doing. Just like learning new vocabulary words, when someone uses a term you don't know, either look it up, or ask them to explain.

Until you are comfortable with those acronyms, you probably want to stay away from a job ad that explicitly requires that particular skillset, because a good interviewer will figure out if you just Googled something last night or if you used it for the past 3 years on a project. Instead, look for junior programming jobs that care more about getting an energetic grad with a good ethic, and low salary requirements than a senior person. Good luck.